# How To Parse JSON with SwiftyJson

Tags: json, swift, xcode, swift2, swifty-json

This is the data

```
[{
  "mineral": "Phosphorus",   
  "data": [ 7.65, 19.74, 15.48 ]
},

{
  "mineral": "Calcium",   
  "data": [ 1.65, 1.32, 1.78 ]
}]
```

And this is the code I used to parse it.

```
if let dataFromString = self.response.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false) {

        let json = JSON(data: dataFromString)

        var valuesB = [Double]()

        for i in 0..<json.count {
            self.nutrient.append(json[i]["mineral"].stringValue)
            print("Nutrient: \(json[i]["mineral"].stringValue)\n")

            for j in 0..<json[i]["data"].count {
                valuesB.append(json[i]["data"][j].doubleValue)
                print("Values: \(json[i]["data"][j].doubleValue)")
            }

            values.append(valuesB)
        }
   }
```

But All I get is

```
Nutrient: Phosphorus

Values: 0.0
Values: 0.0
Values: 0.0

Nutrient: Calcium

Values: 0.0
Values: 0.0
Values: 0.0
```

I was using SwiftyJson for Xcode 7 with Swift, is there another way around this using SwiftyJson?

Comment: Are you sure it's the JSON coming from the server, because it's invalid!! You're missing the comma to separate the elements inside the array.

Comment: I just edited it.

But here's the json array from the server 

http://sanofi.purplebug.net/api/tracker-monthly/09/2016/1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing the conversion of the JSON to a JSON array using the [Optional getters](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON#optional-getter) of SwiftyJSON and the JSON it's not interpreted as an array properly, so you need to use it like in the following code:

```
let jsonString = "[{\"mineral\": \"Phosphorus\",\"data\": [ 7.65, 19.74, 15.48 ]},{\"mineral\": \"Calcium\", \"data\": [ 1.65, 1.32, 1.78 ]}]"

if let dataFromString = jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false) {
        let json = JSON(data: dataFromString)

        // Check if the JSON is an array otherwise nil 
        if let jsonArray = json.array {

            var valuesB = [Double]()

            for i in 0..<jsonArray.count {
                print(jsonArray[i]["mineral"].stringValue)
                print("Nutrient: \(json[i]["mineral"].stringValue)\n")

                for j in 0..<jsonArray[i]["data"].count {
                    valuesB.append(jsonArray[i]["data"][j].doubleValue)
                    print("Values: \(jsonArray[i]["data"][j].doubleValue)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And you should see in the console:

```
Phosphorus
Nutrient: Phosphorus

Values: 7.65
Values: 19.74
Values: 15.48
Calcium
Nutrient: Calcium

Values: 1.65
Values: 1.32
Values: 1.78
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: Wow, that answered it.